# CoordinatorLayout Makes views Unpositioned

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Sorry for my bad English.
I was trying to make scrolling Toolbar with recyclerview using Coordinatorlayout. The scrolling works fine but the views gets under the toolbar,like swipe refresh layout Show in  [image: screenshot].
**Activity_main.xml**
Im implementing a fragment in *FrameLayout* *mobile_container*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.naveed.youtubepro.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:title="@string/app_name">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mobile_container"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
        <me.majiajie.pagerbottomtabstrip.PageNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#FFF"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

**The fragment layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainandroid.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout">
    <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableRecyclerView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Add your all views and ViewsGroup Inside a LinearLayout and make its oriations vertical as mentioned in answer by @Kilran.Thanks....

Comment: <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <!-- frame and bottom navigation -->
</LinearLayout>

Comment: bro its already there

Comment: make width "match_parent"

Comment: where its need match_parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do Like This .Hope this works.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_forget_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:title="@string/app_name">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobile_container"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

            </FrameLayout>
            <me.majiajie.pagerbottomtabstrip.PageNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

Comment: That worked but toolbar is not scrolling  with recyclerview

Comment: @Brown Perhaps you know that " Toolbar should be fixed in a activity" always.

Answer (score 1):

Your LinearLayout holding the recycler view as `android:layout_height="match_parent"` so it will take all the height of the screen bacause the parent is the root layout.

You have to make this LinearLayout take all the height minus the header bar height

You can do this easily :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- frame and bottom navigation -->
</LinearLayout>
```

============== UPDATE ==============

Actually you don't even need this LinearLayout
try this (as suggested by Rahul Kushwaha, wrap the whole thing in LinearLayout but you don't need the inner LinearLayout):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/txt_forget_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:title="@string/app_name">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobile_container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </FrameLayout>
    <me.majiajie.pagerbottomtabstrip.PageNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the views inside layout are now invisible totaly

Answer (score 0):

Set your LinearLayout Property 
`android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: I already tried that but when toolbar scrolls there is a white space between toolbar and other layouts